# Understanding Prime Sieve

Tags: python, primes, sieve

I'm trying to understand a user's implementation of Erastothene's Prime Seive; the code is only a few lines, but I'm having remarkable difficulty understanding it:

```
def eratos_sieve(n):
  sieve = [True] * n
  for i in range(3,int(n**0.5)+1,2):
      if sieve[i]:
          sieve[i*i::2*i]=[False]*((n-i*i-1)//(2*i)+1)
  return len([2] + [i for i in range(3,n,2) if sieve[i]])
```

My unerstanding thus far is this: We're defining a function with a parameter n. We begin by assuming that n is prime. Then, for some reason, we have a for loop with 3 parameters! And after that if statement, I'm just totally lost. If anyone can help, that would be great!

Comment: It starts by assuming all numbers up to `n` are prime, and then marks off the ones that aren't prime as `False`. That is how the sieve works.  The `for` loop skips even numbers by stepping 2 starting from 3: [3, 5, 7, 9, ...]  The third parameter is the step size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps my code commentary below might be of help to you -- I also simplified the code where I could (and hopefully didn't break it!):

```
def eratos_sieve(n):

    ''' Return the number of primes less than n '''

    # Create an array [True, True, True, ...] of length n
    # i.e. assume all numbers are prime unless proven otherwise
    sieve = [True] * n

    # loop over odd numbers from 3 to sqrt(n)
    for i in range(3, int(n**0.5) + 1, 2):

        if sieve[i]:  # if sieve[i] is still True, i is a prime!
            # Assign elements of sieve from i squared to the
            # end of the array skipping by 2 * i (hit multiples
            # of i but skip the even ones) to False. Since this
            # is an array to array assignment, create an array of
            # [False, False, False, ...] of the correct size:
            sieve[i*i::2*i] = [False] * ((n-i * i-1) // (i*2) + 1)

    # Add up odd elements of sieve (True = 1, False = 0),
    # Add one for '2' which we assumed prime:
    return 1 + sum(sieve[3::2])
```

The code is complicated somewhat in that it's skipping over even numbers, which is fine.  A more optimized solution would also reduce the number of elements in `sieve` by half instead of storing the even elements it's ignoring.  This, of course, makes the indexing more complicated, but doable.